# MediaPlayer Error(1, -1004)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to stream my Web Radio with `MediaPlayer` but I get:

> MediaPlayer: error (1,  -1004)

From `setDataSource(url)`:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();

    }

    class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

        protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
            try {
                String url;
                URL completeURL = new URL("http://streaming.radionomy.com/Radio-Mozart.m3u"); 
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(completeURL.openStream()));
                while ((url = in.readLine()) != null) { break; }
                in.close();
                MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
                mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mp.setDataSource(url);
                mp.prepareAsync();
            } catch (Exception e) {}
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

I checked URL and if i put it in my browser, it works. What i do wrong?
I have following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Which setDataSource() API call are you using? I don't see any that match your input.

Comment: This: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You have not passed in a url to setDataSource().</strike>

The only url I see is completeURL or perhaps the set of urls from doInBackground(String... urls);

But, the url variable is one into which you read in a stream from completeURL and stream != url.

Edit:

Your comment indicates that completeURL points to a file whose first line contains another URL. However, you don't just read the first line of the file pointed to by completeURL, you read the *entire* file.

Edit 2:

You may want to reconsider renaming completeURL to fileListURL (or something similar). My answer and other other one posted both misunderstood your intent due to the confusing naming. 3 months from now, you too will make the same mistake when reading your own code.

Edit 3:
As you correctly pointed out, your code only reads the first line of the file pointed to by completeURL. However, when I tried accessing the example given, my browser redirected me to another resource. I suspect setDataSource() needs a url that points directly (no redirects) to the resource being accessed.

At this point, it seems there is something wrong with the url being passed to setDataSource(). You should hardcode the url and verify that it works, then scrutinize the url you read out and check what's wrong with it.

Comment: I pass (the variable 'url' that is a String) a link to the web-radio. I used this: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String)

Comment: Read through your code or look at a debugger to imagine or determine what the *url* variable contains. One possible url is "http:// www.google.com". There are other versions but the variable *url* that you pass to setDataResource does not contain a valid url.

In your code, an example of an actual url string is contained in the variable *completeURL*.

Comment: I am not using setDataResource but setDataSource. The file in "completeURL" variable points to a file .m3u that i open and get the first line:"http://streaming203.radionomy.com:80/Radio-mozart".  This first line is my 'url' variable. So, on which row i get the url "google.com" ????????

Comment: Ah, I see. You're reading the URL from the file pointed to by completeURL. The problem is you are reading the entire file, not just one line. (btw, the setDataResource was a typo, I meant setDataSource).

Comment: With while ((url = in.readLine()) != null) { break; } i read only first row of the file. On the first row of the file i get the real url of the web radio

Comment: Hmm, that's correct. So I tried opening "streaming203.radionomy.com:80/Radio-mozart" in my browser. It starts playing music, but displays a URL of http://streaming.radionomy.com/RadionoMiX. That suggests to me that there is a redirect occuring. I'm guessing that setDataSource() expects a direct url to the resource it needs to access.

Comment: No redirect occurring. RadionoMiX is because when you put a wrong URL, he redirects to "radionoMY default radio". If you open the file ("http://streaming.radionomy.com/Radio-Mozart.m3u") now, you get this http://streaming210.radionomy.com:80/Radio-Mozart on first row that works without redirects

Comment: Hmm, then in that case, your options to figure out what is wrong is to 1: Hardcode the correct url and make sure it opens with setDataSource. Then 2. Check the url that you are reading and see what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you're calling the wrong `setDataSource` method.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(java.lang.String)) the method you're using is expecting a FilePath. You need to call [`setDataSource(context, Uri)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setDataSource(android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri)) instead. (The context to use is `MainActivity.this`)

The file you're using seems to have an invalid url at the last line. Instead of

```
while ((url = in.readLine()) != null) { break; }
```

use

```
url = in.readLine();
```

leaving your code like this

```
    protected Void doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {
            String url;
            URL completeURL = new URL("http://streaming.radionomy.com/Radio-Mozart.m3u"); 
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(completeURL.openStream()));
            url = in.readLine();
            in.close();
            URL url = new URL(thisUrl);
            Uri.Builder builder;
            builder =  new Uri.Builder()
                        .scheme(url.getProtocol())
                        .authority(url.getAuthority())
                        .appendPath(url.getPath());
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mp.setDataSource(MainActivity.this,builder.build());
            mp.prepareAsync();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: I tried setDataSource(context,Uri) but i get the same error. The BufferedReader that i use is because the "real url" is contained in   the file pointed by "completeURL" variable (because can change). I have not files: i can't use that method

Comment: What's the content of url when you instance it? I'm guessing that you may have a blank line at the end which is causing your problem. See my amended answer. Mind you: I added a conversion from URL to URI as well.